# on click the control's size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input type as below with me for the Date of Birth.

```
<div class="input-div spanicon">
   <input placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" class="textbox-n" type="text" id="txtDOB"> 
   <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="triggerCal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cndb49eh/) for the same.

On click of the icon, field's size changes, Can someone help on this.

Comment: you can assign `max-width:120px;`

Comment: check updated fiddle here :https://jsfiddle.net/anupam_001/cndb49eh/4/

Answer (score 0):

Give a static width to input

```js
 // Event to trigger the calendar in the signup page
 $("#triggerCal").click(function() {
   $("#txtDOB").attr("type", "date");
   $("#txtDOB").focus();
   $("#txtDOB").click();
 });

 // Focus out event of the textbox
 $("body").on("focusout", "#txtDOB", function() {
   $("#txtDOB").attr("type", "text");
 });
```

```css
body.signup-page .login-form form input {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

style.css:841 .input-div.spanicon input {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
}

style.css:275 .login-form form input {
  background-color: #ebf7fa;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 45px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.28);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.28);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.28);
}
.textbox-n{
  width:180px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-div spanicon">
  <input placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" class="textbox-n" type="text" id="txtDOB">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="triggerCal" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Comment: Will this be responsive for all the devices? Also for some reason, It gets different styles on it all together.

Comment: For responsiveness, you should use @media queries, then you can change the different size on different viewports

Answer (score 0):

This happen `type=text` change to `type=date` and applies different style. this is just a simple trick.

```html
<div class="input-div spanicon">
  <input placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" class="textbox-n" type="text" id="txtDOB" onfocus="(this.type='date')">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="triggerCal" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the size of `date input` same as `input text` i.e. onclick then try as below,

```js
 // Event to trigger the calendar in the signup page
  $("#triggerCal").click(function(){
     var itp = $(".textbox-n").width();
     var dt = $("#txtDOB").attr("type","date");
     $(dt).focus();
     $(dt).click();
     $(dt).css({
     width : itp
     });
  });

  // Focus out event of the textbox
  $("body").on("focusout","#txtDOB",function(){
     $("#txtDOB").attr("type","text");
  });
```

```css
body.signup-page .login-form form input {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
style.css:841
.input-div.spanicon input {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
}
style.css:275
.login-form form input {
    background-color: #ebf7fa;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 45px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.28);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.28);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50,0.28);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-div spanicon">
                  <input placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" class="textbox-n" type="text" id="txtDOB"> 
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="triggerCal" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```